# React CSS Style is getting overridden

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

I have a react application which uses 3rd party libraries to create components.

The problem I am facing is one library css is getting loaded from CDN and other through node_modules. The css coming from CDN is overriding the css from other libraries.

CSS from CDN is written as -

```
.solar-theme button {
// css properties 
}
```

CSS from other library is as -

```
.some-button {
// css properties 
}
```

And button component in this library uses ***solar-theme*** as classname.

How to isolate the CSS coming from CDN to a single react component so that it doesn't overrides the other library css?
I am new to UI/UX. Please help.

Comment: You need to make use of CSS specificity: https://specifishity.com/

Comment: I cannot edit the library css. I want the css from the 2nd library to apply not from the cdn.

Comment: But that's how CSS works. You cannot separate it to a single component. It is applied all over your page so it will override unless you are making using of specificity or using layers if it's your stylesheet.

Comment: I think this should help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't edit the CSS files from the libraries, you should write a new stylesheet to override certain properties as you come across them.
You might also have to use `important!` to enforce your properties.
For example:

```
/* Your custom stylesheet */
.some-button {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

If this does not work (it probably won't), you need to be more specific with your declarations.

**Generally, the more specific you can be, the higher the chance of your style getting applied** (when there are conflicting stylesheets).

So you can upgrade the declaration above by doing something like this instead:

```
/* Your custom stylesheet */
footer .container .some-button {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

It's called specificity. You can read more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity